# how can i use a vector in multiple .cpp and header files simultanously?

Tags: c++

i have a main.cpp and some classes which each of them is defined in two files: a header and a .cpp file.
in the main.cpp i have a 2d vector. I want to use this vector in the member functions of the classes.first i tried to include the main file, but i received the redefinition Error. after that i tried to define the vector in another .h file. but that didn't work either.
so what should i do to use this vector in the defining of some classes, in that way that it could save the changes which member functions made.

unfortunately the vector is global!

for more information this vector is board of a game. this game has some objects: a monster, a human, a treasure and some traps. 
the board is defined global before the main function. there are some functions in main.cpp that use this board, and classes which i mentioned 3 lines above, use this board in their member functions.

is solution using 'extern'?(i don't know what it is, i just saw it in answers!-if it's the solution, i should search about it.)

Comment: Lookup the  `extern` keyword in your C/C++ reference documentation. That said, use a reference parameter and forget the idea of a global unless this entire program is less than about 25 lines of code.

Comment: Is this a global variable (bad idea)? A local variable in main() or some other function? That kind of stuff is important if we are to help you.

Comment: Pass it by reference into the relevant functions.

Comment: unfortunately the vector is global!

Comment: @komeilshahhosseini: are you for some reason constrained to have a global vector? It would be a much better idea to redesign your code so that the global vector no longer exists; see my comment on one of the answers below for more details.

Comment: @drewmm thanks, the reason is that I'm new to C++ and don't know how to work with references and pointers yet.

Comment: That's fair. I'd still recommend learning about references (they're not as scary as they seem) and get the design right this time, rather than practicing a poor way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Main.cpp

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::vector<int>> myArray;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   // blah...
   myArray.add(5);
}
```

and in your other file:

```
#include <vector>

extern std::vector<std::vector<int>> myArray;
```

using the **extern** keyword allows you to tell the compiler "Hey, this object right here, it doesn't exist...  But don't worry!  You'll find it once the linker assembles the compiled objects!".

You can also use the "**extern**" keyword to load serialized data (like bmp2c, which makes a .c file that contains the picture's binary data)

EDIT: Also, it's important that the 2 objects have the exact same name (case sensitive).

Comment: by using extern i don't have any error anymore, but the changes that are made to the vector, doesn't save on it, in other words it doesn't change at all!

Comment: You mean when you close the program and re-open it?  That's normal, it shouldn't.  If you want it to save your vector when you alter it, you'll need to write a parser of some sort, and manually read/write the file to load/save the vector.

Answer (score 0):

You may write it like this:
**a.h**

```
extern vector< vector<int> > vec2D; //declare the 2d vector here
```

**a.cpp**

```
#include "a.h"    
vector< vector<int> > vec2D;  //define the 2d vector here
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "a.h"
//use the 2d vector here
```

Comment: That would *work*. But it's worth pointing out that it's not a very good way to design the code. It's much better to put the game board vector into a class that represents the game, and then to pass a reference to an instance of that class around to any function that needs to interact with the game (or, even better, define functions that edit the game as class methods of the game class.)

Comment: @Snail   
as i said, i want to use this vector in defining of some classes too. when i include the header file which the vector is defined in, i get an error :Error 18 error LNK2005: "class std::vector<class std::vector<char,class std::allocator<char> >,class std::allocator<class std::vector<char,class std::allocator<char> > > > board" (?board@@3V?$vector@V?$vector@DV?$allocator@D@std@@@std@@V?$allocator@V?$vector@‌​DV?$allocator@D@std@@@std@@@2@@std@@A) already defined in header.obj E:\lab and python programming\c++ advanced programming\main.obj what should i do with this now?!!