# C++ Trying to write a method that changes a value in an extern vector

Tags: c++, class, oop, vector, extern

so I have three files here that are important:
main.cpp, common.h, EngineScript.cpp. I am declaring my multidimensional vector in common as `extern vector<vector<string>> PositionVector(vector<string>);`

I  am defining it in main.cpp with

```
    vector<vector<string>> PositionVector(20,vector<string>(20," ")); //populates the vector with a string, in this case, a space
```

my method looks like this in EngineScript.cpp

```
class EngineObject : public EngineFunct{
public:
int objectXcord = 0;
int objectYcord = 0;
string objectIcon = "?";

void spawnObject(){
PositionVector[objectXcord][objectYcord] = objectIcon;
         }
     };
```

this does not work.
it throws these errors

```
In file included from /home/jake/vstests/C++/ncurses_projects/ncurses_2dengineproject/main.cpp:17:
/home/jake/vstests/C++/ncurses_projects/ncurses_2dengineproject/EngineScript.cpp: In member function ‘void EngineObject::spawnObject()’:
/home/jake/vstests/C++/ncurses_projects/ncurses_2dengineproject/EngineScript.cpp:50:31: warning: pointer to a function used in arithmetic [-Wpointer-arith]
   50 |     PositionVector[objectXcord][objectYcord] = objectIcon;
      |                               ^
/home/jake/vstests/C++/ncurses_projects/ncurses_2dengineproject/EngineScript.cpp:50:44: warning: pointer to a function used in arithmetic [-Wpointer-arith]
   50 |     PositionVector[objectXcord][objectYcord] = objectIcon;
      |                                            ^
/home/jake/vstests/C++/ncurses_projects/ncurses_2dengineproject/EngineScript.cpp:50:46: error: assignment of read-only location ‘*(PositionVector + (((sizetype)((EngineObject*)this)->EngineObject::objectXcord) + ((sizetype)((EngineObject*)this)->EngineObject::objectYcord)))’
   50 |     PositionVector[objectXcord][objectYcord] = objectIcon;
      |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Engine.dir/build.make:76: CMakeFiles/Engine.dir/main.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:83: CMakeFiles/Engine.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2>
```

whats really grinding my gears right now is that if i get rid of the contents of `spawnObject()`
and put `PositionVector[obj.objectXcord][obj.objectYcord] = obj.objectIcon;` into main.cpp, it does work, it works fine with no errors or bugs and does almost what I wanted. Its late, I am not that great at C++ and I can't seem to find anything helpful on the interwebs. what simple mistake am I making? thanks in advance

edit 1
after making the changes recommended by john, it gets farther along but still gives errors, just these ones look more annoying

````
[ 25%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/Engine.dir/main.cpp.o
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/Engine.dir/EngineScript.cpp.o
[ 75%] Linking CXX executable Engine
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/Engine.dir/main.cpp.o: warning: relocation against `_Z14PositionVectorB5cxx11' in read-only section `.text._ZN12EngineObject11spawnObjectEv[_ZN12EngineObject11spawnObjectEv]'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/Engine.dir/main.cpp.o: in function `EngineObject::spawnObject()':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN12EngineObject11spawnObjectEv[_ZN12EngineObject11spawnObjectEv]+0x23): undefined reference to `PositionVector[abi:cxx11]'
/usr/bin/ld: warning: creating DT_TEXTREL in a PIE
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Engine.dir/build.make:129: Engine] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:83: CMakeFiles/Engine.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2```
````

Comment: Sorry to be a pedant but the phrase 'throws an error' really bugs me. In C++ exceptions are thrown, not compiler errors. You could say emits an error I suppose, but not throws an error.

Comment: Please copy-paste the errors you get as is, formatted as code. Don't reformat all the lines into a single line.

Comment: `extern vector<vector<string>> PositionVector(vector<string>)` is [most vexing parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28094774/most-vexing-parse-c11).

Comment: @Jason Not really, it's just a plain normal standard function declaration.

Comment: One question per question please. If you get a new and different problem when please post it as a new and different question.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Here is the correct duplicate: [How do you declare a global std::vector 2d array across multiple files? c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43835726/how-do-you-declare-a-global-stdvector-2d-array-across-multiple-files-c). Here is another [how can i use a vector in multiple .cpp and header files simultanously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15793465/how-can-i-use-a-vector-in-multiple-cpp-and-header-files-simultanously)

Comment: Just don't use globals, create your vector somewhere (e.g. main) and then pass it on (by reference or copy) to constructors of classes that need access to it. Or put all your "globals" in a class, derive that class from an abstract baseclass with getters and pass the interface to classes/code that needs "global" information (this will make your code unit testable). Lookup dependency injection online

Comment: Why my advice: Your current approach will tie a lot of classes and source files together making them dependent on each other and that will become more and more problematic as the size of your project goes. For a game you must design for unit testability, for build times you want your files to be as independent as you can. And for both you need to model your dependencies as interfaces (abstract baseclasses)

Comment: after some fiddling, it threw some more errors and somewhere started working, I don't know what did it and actually didn't think anything changed since I started. Arrgh. Sorry future people who end up having the same problem, I don't know what fixed it.

Comment: @setanta I guess that your second error was caused by a partial rebuild. So you changed the common.h file but did not recompile all the source files that depended on it.

Answer (score 1):

In common.h

```
extern vector<vector<string>> PositionVector(vector<string>);
```

should be

```
extern vector<vector<string>> PositionVector;
```

Your version declares a function called `PositionVector` which is confusing the compiler.

Judging by the errors you get it seems that you are not including common.h in main.cpp. If so then this is a mistake. You should always include the header file that makes a global declaration in the cpp file that makes the corresponding global definition. This gives the compiler a chance to check that the global declaration and global definition are consistent. Something that is not true in the code above.

Comment: I forgot to uncomment it while troubleshooting, but I am still getting errors

Comment: @setanta If you are getting new errors, you need to ask a new question.

Comment: @setanta Ask a new question for your follow up question(s). Don't edit the current post by adding new errors into it. Since there is already an answer explaining the problem for the old errors. One question per post should be posted.